# mpi run command error : process excited without calling finalize

Tags: c

I'm making an MPI program with Visual studio and a problem occurred.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(void) {
int a[1000], b[1000];
int my_rank, p;
int source = 0, tag = 5;
int count[100], result = 0;
MPI_Status status;

MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);

srand(time(NULL));

if (my_rank == 0) {
    for (int j = 0; j < p; j++) {
        for (int i = j / p; i < 1000 * ((j+1) / p); i++) {
            a[i] = rand() % 100;
            MPI_Send(a[i], 1, MPI_INT, j, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    }
    printf("&d", a[30]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000 / p; i++) {
        MPI_Recv(&b[i], 1, MPI_INT, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        if (b[i] % 2 != 0) {
            count[my_rank] += b[i];
        }
    }
}

else if (my_rank != 0) {
    count[my_rank] = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000 / p; j++) {
        MPI_Recv(&b[j], 1, MPI_INT, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        if (b[j] % 2 != 0) {
            count[my_rank] += b[j];
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
    result += count[i];
}

printf("The sum of the odd numbers is %d.", result);

MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
```

}

If I run the code above (I inserted mpiexec -n 4 HW1.exe at the command prompt), I get an error message like this :

0: samsungpc: 0xc0000005: process excited without calling finalize
1: samsungpc: terminated
2: samsungpc: terminated
3: samsungpc: terminated

---error analysis---
0: HW1.exe ended prematurely and may have crashed on samsungpc
---error analysis---

Comment: Maybe this is not the only problem but this : MPI_Send(a[i], 1, MPI_INT, j, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD); should be MPI_Send(&a[i], 1, MPI_INT, j, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);